# Symfony 5.1 to 5.2 unit testing do not authenticate via guard authenticator

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, authenticator

I 'm working with Symfony 5.1 using the firewall and a guard authenticator;

```
        secured_area:
        pattern:  ^/
        stateless: true
        provider: chain_provider
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\<pathToAuthenticator>
            entry_point: App\<pathToAuthenticator>
```

All was working fine with 5.1.
I've recently upgrade to Symfony 5.2 and almost all working fine except Unit tests.
When i do a step by step debugging, it's not stepping into the `Authenticator` anymore like it was the case previously (in 5.1).

Any parameter missing in my configuration ? Default parameter have change ?

Comment: Any chance that you added 'enable_authenticator_manager: true' to your security.yaml file?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have modified my conf and add "enable_authenticator_manager: true", got some deprecation warning, resolve them. But still the same pb. The weirdest is that it's working well in the browser and postman ... only not working in unit testing.

Comment: The reason I asked is because you don't want to set it.  The flag enables a new experimental authentication process.  One that does not use guard authenticators at all which sort of fits your description.  In any event, unless you are using the new authenticators you should set it back to false.  The only other suggestion I can think of is to run 'bin/console debug:config security' and compare the results to your 5.1 app.

Comment: i have ran a  "bin/console debug:config security" on both versions and compare with a diff, they are strictly identical.

Comment: Any chance of making a gist out of one of the failing functional tests?  It's possible a BC break slipped in but there is no easy way to investigate it without code.

Comment: I have not completely found the reason yet, but while restarting a project to investigate i have been surprised by a weird comportment : when you create a request in units tests, you have to put header in uppercase, otherwise they are ignored ! HTTP_Accept => not working in 5.2, working in 5.1 and HTTP_ACCEPT => working in 5.2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, i 've found the pb, and the solution, in my test do :

```
self::$_client->request(
    'GET',
    '/items',
    array(),
    array(),
    array('HTTP_Accept' => 'application/json', 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'),
    json_encode($payload)
);
```

And i have a request matcher that filter on JSON request :

```
class JsonRequestMatcher implements RequestMatcherInterface
{
    public function matches(Request $request)
    {
        $format = $request->getPreferredFormat();
        return $format === "json";
    }
}
```

For a reason i have not determined, when the header send 'HTTP_Accept' **$format** value in the request matcher is "html" and the request is not processed ... then it crash futher on.

When i change 'HTTP_Accept' to 'HTTP_ACCEPT', (yes, just upper case the header !) it works, and the value for $**format** is the one expected (ie :  "json").
Thanks to Cerad for his support and for some commands i just don't know was existing in Symfony ;-)